# complete the table by providing an example of a binary operation $*$ defined on $\{a , b ,c\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a problem with one of my questions. The question is:

complete the table by providing an example of a binary operation $*$ defined on $\{a , b ,c\}$
such that $*$ is commutative and has the identity element $c$.
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\ast & a & b & c \\ 
\hline
a & a & ? & ? \\ 
b & ? & b & ? \\ 
c & ? & ? & c \\ 
\end{array}

(I need the letters in place of the ?)

I don't understand what they want me to do ???

Answer (score 3):

$c$ is the identity and the operation is commutative so $$a\cdot c=c\cdot a=a$$ Similarly $$b\cdot c=c\cdot b=b$$ It seems to me that $a\cdot b$ can be $a$ or $b$.

Comment: $a\cdot b$ could also be $c$.

Answer (score 3):

You have to fill out the [Cayley table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_table) such that the operation is commutative with identity element 'c'. There is more than one way to accomplish that, for example the operation a*b=max{a,b} with (a,b,c) = (2,1,0) will satisfy the preconditions given in the table.

Answer (score 0):

For $a$ to be the identity element, it must be $a\ast b=b=b\ast a$ and $a\ast c=c=c\ast a$, so you have:
\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\ast & a & b & c \\ 
\hline
a & a & \color{lime}{b} & \color{lime}{c}\\ 
b & \color{lime}{b} & b & ? \\ 
c & \color{lime}{c} & ? & c \\ 
\end{array}
Then, for commutativity to hold, this is for the Cayley table to be symmetric, you have only three choices:

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\ast & a & b & c \\ 
\hline
a & a & b & c\\ 
b & b & b & \color{red}{a} \\ 
c & c & \color{red}{a} & c \\ 
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\ast & a & b & c \\ 
\hline
a & a & b & c\\ 
b & b & b & \color{red}{b} \\ 
c & c & \color{red}{b} & c \\ 
\end{array}

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\ast & a & b & c \\ 
\hline
a & a & b & c\\ 
b & b & b & \color{red}{c} \\ 
c & c & \color{red}{c} & c \\ 
\end{array}

Exactly at the same way, you have three choices if $b$ is the identity, and three more if the identity is $c$. In this last case:

\begin{array}{c|ccc}
\ast & a & b & c \\ 
\hline
a & a & ? & \color{lime}{a}\\ 
b & ? & b & \color{lime}{b} \\ 
c & \color{lime}{a} & \color{lime}{b} & c \\ 
\end{array}
and so on, as above.

Answer (score 0):

Let a binary operation $*$ on N be defined b $a*b=HCF$ of $a$ and $b$.

Construct a composition Tabe that the set $H=(1,2,3,4,5,6,)$ is closed under $*$.